# macOS Hight Sierra / Mojave: Programmatically get value of "System Preferences -> Accessibility -> Display -> Increase contrast"

Tags: macos-high-sierra, macos-mojave

How programmatically get value of **Increase contrast** setting on macOS Hight Sierra? Also interesting to know how to observe that value change.

Full path to system preference is **System Preferences -> Accessibility -> Display -> Increase contrast**.

[image]

On macOS Mojave it can be achieved via `effectiveAppearance.bestMatch` API call like below.

```
open override func layout() {
  super.layout()
  if #available(OSX 10.14, *) {
     if let value = effectiveAppearance.bestMatch(from: [.aqua, .darkAqua, .accessibilityHighContrastAqua, .accessibilityHighContrastDarkAqua]) {

        switch value {
        case .aqua:
           setupAppearance(.light)
        case .darkAqua:
           setupAppearance(.dark)
        case .accessibilityHighContrastAqua:
           setupAppearance(.highContrastLight)
        case .accessibilityHighContrastDarkAqua:
           setupAppearance(.highContrastDark)
        default:
           break
        }

     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting on macOS 10.10 you can use this API of NSWorkspace.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1526290-accessibilitydisplayshouldincrea